# angular js plugin is not found in pinegrow version 2.951

Tags: angularjs

I am not getting **angularjs plugin** in properties of *todo.html* page at new version **pinegrow 2.951** . While creating new page it will add, but while editing it will not show ..Please help me

Comment: Some screenshot may help...

Comment: Sorry, since I din't added js file, i din't find the plugin